# FB ios SDK 3.13.1 The operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)

Tags: ios, facebook

I have been using FB iOS SDK 3.13.1 in my app and Login is working fine until I setup facebook account in Settings->Facebook. I couldn't login using FB at all. It was kept giving me error :The operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)

I tried all suggestions mentioned on stackoverflow. Changing facebook app settings or handle openURL but none worked.

But If I removed account from settings->facebook. Login worked. So I did setup all things correctly as instructed.

Not sure, what's wrong but I think FB SDK is very unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. after lot of searching and tries, I realized its just issue with Facebook ios SDK. Hence upgraded to 3.14.1 and its working fine. I even tried to reproduce the issue with an older build and try same scenario number of times.